# Internet Radio Player + Last.fm Submission

Tags: last.fm, internet-radio

Does anyone know of an internet radio player (for Linux) which will submit streamed tracks to last.fm?

I've a [stream](http://network.absoluteradio.co.uk/core/audio/aacplus/live.pls?service=a9bb) which announces what the current track is, but my current player (rhythmbox) doesn't update last.fm.

I don't hold out much hope having read [this](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=376659) bug post, but at least I want to see if anyone knows for sure.

Answer (score 1):

[Banshee](http://banshee.fm/).

> Play your music and videos. Keep up with your podcasts and Internet radio. Discover new music and podcasts. Keep your portable device loaded with good stuff.
>
> Simple enough to enjoy. Powerful enough to thrill. Open source through and through.
>
> [image]

Comment: Finally got to it behave, but whilst it notifies me of the track each time it changes, it never actually submits the track to last.fm (unlike when I'm playing local music). Back to square one!

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://www.last.fm/forum/21713/_/454698/1) thread online radio streams can't be scrobbled in rhythmbox. But I use [this](http://kyleabaker.com/2009/10/06/pandora-internet-radio-plus-last-fm-scrobbling/) firefox extension to scrobble pandora internet radio